# Bootstrap Nav bar, remove list items dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use jQuery to remove the list items of Bootstrap Nav Bar by using the following jQuery code. The code run but the list items didn't remove. Please help! -The following are the html code and Javascript code :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="home" class="active">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="Home.html"> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="add" class="inactive">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="Add.html">Add</a>
                </li>
                   <li id="search" class="inactive">
                   <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="Search.html">Search</a>
                </li>
                <li id="admin" class="inactive">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="Admin.html">Admin</a>
                </li>
                   <li id="my" class="inactive">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="my.html">My Profile</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("role_admin") != "1") {
      $("#add").remove();
      $("#admin").remove();
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are fetching role_admin value from sessionStorage.
But how you are storing it there? You have not mentioned it.
Are you sure that the if condition executes?

Comment: Yes, I am storing sessionStorage.role_admin value when user logging in.

Comment: Is removing them cosmetic or for security as well? If for security reasons (whatever they may be) you shouldn't use javascript to remove the links.

Comment: Try with this:
if (sessionStorage.getItem("role_admin") !==  "1")
OR
if (sessionStorage.getItem("role_admin") !=  1)

Comment: It is for security reasons. I am removing the link and when user access the admin page I also check sessionStorage.role_admin value.

Comment: console errors logged? Where are you loading your jQuery and what version are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First please look at the second `<script>` tag, you're not closing it.

Comment: I did close the tag in my actual code. I just updated with closing tag,

Comment: It works for me in this pen https://codepen.io/ilyanice/pen/MomJOM. Did you add jQuery into your script?

Comment: Yes, I did add jQuery reference into my script. Thanks for show me your codeine.io code. I need to double check my sessionStorage.role_admin value.

Comment: It work now after I add this code if ( (sessionStorage.getItem("role_admin") != "1")  || (sessionStorage.getItem("role_admin")  != 1 ) {